# Jquery Mmenu previous button not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, mmenu

I'm trying to create a menu that has rich content (panels with advanced HTML).
I've followed the docs on the mmenu site, but see the previous button (the button that transitions the menu back to the previous slide) is missing.
On further inspection, I see that the element is there, but does not have any inner HTML (needed for the css arrow to appear) nor is it tracking which panel I am currently on:

```
<div class="body container">
  <div class="row">
  <nav id="component-menu" class="row col-xs-4">
    <div id="home" class="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#style-components-panel">Style Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="#select-components-panel">Select Components</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="style-components-panel" class="styling-menu row">
      <div class="col-xs-6"><p>Effect all components</p></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <label class="switch">
          <input id="effectAllComponents" type="checkbox" checked>
          <div class="slider round"></div>
        </label>                                                
      </div>
      <div id="colorPicker" class="color-picker col-xs-12"></div>
      <div id="color-field-container" class="col-xs-12 row"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="select-components-panel" class="component-menu row">
      <div id="component-container" class="row component-container">
        <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product">
          <img src="imgs/product.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
        </div>
        <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_large">
          <img src="imgs/product_large.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
        </div>
        <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="products">
          <img src="imgs/products.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
        </div>
        <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_alt">
          <img src="imgs/product_alt.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
        </div>
        <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_center">
          <img src="imgs/product_center.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
        </div>
        <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_small">
          <img src="imgs/product_small.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="mm-page col-xs-8">
      <p>hello mukhtar</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/hwh596eu/2/)

I thought my HTML structure was bad, but I see that one of the demos on the doc site is achieving something close to what I want (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/index.html?demo=app-settings&menu=default), with the same high level structure as my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

through some more experimentation, I found that my HTML was a tad bit off.
the anchors in the LI elements I created should have been spans in the LI's and the section they were linking to should also be in the same LI

```
<div class="body container">
 <div class="row">
  <nav id="component-menu" class="row col-xs-4">
    <div id="home" class="">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span>Style Components</span>
          <div id="style-components-panel" class="styling-menu row">
            <div class="col-xs-6"><p>Effect all components</p></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
              <label class="switch">
                <input id="effectAllComponents" type="checkbox" checked>
                <div class="slider round"></div>
              </label>                                              
            </div>
            <div id="colorPicker" class="color-picker col-xs-12"></div>
            <div id="color-field-container" class="col-xs-12 row"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Select Components</span>
          <div id="select-components-panel" class="component-menu row">
            <div id="component-container" class="row component-container">
              <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product">
                <img src="imgs/product.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
              </div>
              <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_large">
                <img src="imgs/product_large.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
              </div>
              <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="products">
                <img src="imgs/products.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
              </div>
              <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_alt">
                <img src="imgs/product_alt.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
              </div>
              <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_center">
                <img src="imgs/product_center.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
              </div>
              <div class="component col-xs-12" data-id="product_small">
                <img src="imgs/product_small.jpg" width="280" height="98" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="mm-page col-xs-8">
  <p>hello joe</p>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hwh596eu/4/